# Heroku worker can't access database

Tags: django, heroku, worker

I have a Django project hosted by Heroku with a (postgresql) database, an app that interacts with that database (on a web dyno), and a worker that should also interact with the database.

The app asks the worker to do long running tasks in the background, like some database queries. However, I'm having trouble implementing this. I think the problem is that the worker is not authorized to access the database. The specific error I'm seeing is:

`app[worker.1]: ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

This doesn't make sense to me as an error coming from the worker. The settings are getting loaded fine- everything on the web dyno works as expected. The only thing I can figure is that the worker doesn't have access to the configured settings, including the database credentials.

How do I resolve this?

**Edit:**
Here's the Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi --log-file -
worker: python launchworker.py
```

As indicated there, the worker is launched as a Heroku worker, and it isn't run through the Django project at all (as I understand would be the case if it were a management command). [This was the method recommended by Heroku.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq)

Comment: You need to at least show the Procfile.

Comment: Is your worker process implemented as a Django management command?